# juju: ERROR Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT

Tags: cloud, juju, maas

I'm trying to realize an Ubuntu Enterprise Infrastructure using virtualBox creating all VMs. After I followed this tutorials:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/AddNodes

without have issues. When use the following guides:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Juju
- http://marcoceppi.com/2012/05/juju-maas-virtualbox/

my environments.yaml's file is:

```
environments:
  vb-maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://192.168.0.10:80/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: '***ssh_key***'
    admin-secret: 'nothing'
    default-series: 'precise'
```

but when I run

```
sudo juju bootstrap
```

receive this error

```
2012-06-29 23:55:33,568 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'vb-maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT
2012-06-29 23:55:34,475 ERROR Unexpected Error interacting with provider: 409 CONFLICT
```

why? someone will help me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It means that the maas server has no nodes to allocate to juju, this has been changed to a more useful error message in more recent version of the juju in precise.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/980855

Comment: when I open the maas server web interface I see my nodes added. I also selected Wake On LAN and clicked on Accept & Commission for each one. thanks for the link

Comment: I also checked that on its web interface for each node there is this note: "You can boot this node using Avahi enabled boot media or an adequately configured dhcp server, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/AvahiBoot for details."

Comment: @RiccardoMagrini Did this answer fix the problem for you?